# Get the current time to the nearest minute without the use of MySQL now()

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for solution to get current time rounded to minutes without using now() in MySQL. The point of this is get a query which will be handled by Query cache at least for minute. With uses of now() query is changed every second and Query cache isn't used as often as is permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query cache will never cache queries that use non-deterministic functions, and all time functions are by definition nondeterministic.

Your best option is to build the time string in your application and pass the entire query to MySQL.

> A query cannot be cached if it
>   contains any of the functions shown in
>   the following table.
>
> ```
> BENCHMARK()
> CONNECTION_ID()   CONVERT_TZ()
> CURDATE()     CURRENT_DATE()
> CURRENT_TIME() CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
> CURTIME()     DATABASE() ENCRYPT() with one parameter     
> FOUND_ROWS()
> GET_LOCK() LAST_INSERT_ID()
> LOAD_FILE()   MASTER_POS_WAIT() NOW()
> RAND()    RELEASE_LOCK() SLEEP()
> SYSDATE()     UNIX_TIMESTAMP() with no parameters 
> USER()    UUID()
> UUID_SHORT()
> ```
>
> A query also is not cached under these
>   conditions:
>
> - It refers to user-defined functions (UDFs) or stored functions.
> - It refers to user variables or local stored program variables
>
> [...]

Comment: Yes it's the best way to create a time in application and I did it where it was possible, but I'm facing a problem where I can't simply generate time in application and need to do the same in MySQL. Thanks anyway for answer.

Comment: As I can say after searching for solution, there's no other way than you wrote. So someone have to shape application the way that you can pass it like parameter from app. Thanks.